# disable function in other function

Tags: php, function, security

for example I want disable function mail() or fsockopen() if these calls on eval() function.
but other way function work.

```
eval(mail()); // mail() disable;

mail();// it's work
```

any way to do this?

Comment: you can't disable it like this, but you can disable through php.ini and its disable complete function even you call in `eval()` or direct.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a string to the ['eval'-function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

This means it's quite easy to check the string before evaluating it:

```
$function = "mail()";
if (!preg_match('/\bmail *\(/', $function))
{
    eval($function);
}
```